# Can we sort the report folders in selenium- Cucumber maven framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, selenium-extent-report

I am using Selenium - Cucumber Maven framework. I have written the code for creating report logs on each run. After each run, report folders are creating with appending timestamp. But the report folders are not displaying in sorted order. ie, latest created report folder to be at the top . Do we have any method to do like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folders on your screenshot are sorted properly if the folder names are seen as strings.

The strings

```
15
5
50
```

are properly sorted as 1 would be before 5.

The numbers

```
5
15
50
```

should probably be sorted as above if you want them in ascending order.

If you want the folders sorted differently, you will need to look at the source for Eclipse and adjust the order folders are displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually what i need is to create new report folders in sorted order like : newly created report folder to be at the top of the list .

Comment: I see, then I think you need to look into the plugin that writes the reports and see if you can do something there. But it might be a good thing to notice that the reports are written in the ./target directory which might disappear anytime as in someone running mvn clean

Comment: I just noticed that the reports written in the ./target directory is disappeared after running mvn clean. is this will create any issues ?

Comment: That's what I warned you about. The stuff in ./target is ephemeral and will disappear if anyone does mvn clean. That's by design and how Maven works.

Comment: If these reports are valuable to you, make sure you copy them to a safe place after each build.

Comment: yeah okay @ Thomas .. Thank you